# Всем здравствуйте, хотела спросить один клопотливый вопрос

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я пишу книгу и там у меня есть два брата кузница Грог и Грол. Их слуга идёт к другому персонажу и представляется как "Я от госпадинов ..." У братьев есть что-то на типе клички или фамилии "Горн". Вопрос: как правильно вписать эту фамилию: от госпадинов Горн, от госпадинов Горнов или есть какой-то другой вариант??? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Gorn/skloneniye.html#:~:text=Склонение%20фамилии%20Горн%20по%20падежам,(О%20ком%3F)%20Горне%20Горн%20Горнах

Comment: Комментарии посетителей  Дата: 25.03.2016 13:45:14
У меня в паспорте регистрация с Горном, а у других родственников - Горн. Работник паспортного стола говорит, что у меня правильно, а у других не правильно. Так ли это?   https://surnameonline.ru/surname-39481.html

Comment: От госпадинов, клопотливый, да...))

Comment: Артем, это белорусский вариант, вероятно. Но вопросы надо по-русски задавать. Переводчик есть, если что.

Comment: Ой, точно, похоже, даже не догадался!

Answer (score 1):

1. Фамилия Горн  **[склоняется](https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Gorn/skloneniye.html#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BC,(%D0%9E%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%3F)%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85)**, так как оканчивается на **согласный** и относится к **мужчинам**.
2. **Отступления** наблюдаются в тех случаях, когда фамилия созвучна с названием предмета неодушевленного **[горн](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD).** В этом случае учитывается запись фамилии **в паспорте.**

**ПРАВИЛО**

[§151, пункт 4. Склонение некоторых имен и фамилий](https://evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_06)

Русские и иноязычные фамилии, оканчивающиеся на **согласный** звук, **склоняются,** если относятся к мужчинам, и не склоняются, если относятся к женщинам. Ср.: студенту Кулику – студентке Кулик, у Джорджа Буша – у Барбары Буш. **Частые отступления от правила (несклоняемость русских мужских фамилий,** оканчивающихся на согласный звук) наблюдаются в тех случаях, когда фамилия созвучна с названием животного или **предмета неодушевленного** (Гусь, Ремень), во избежание непривычных или курьезных сочетаний, например: «У господина Гуся», «гражданину Ремню».

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос: как правильно вписать эту фамилию: от госпадинов Горн, от госпадинов Горнов или есть какой-то другой вариант???

В русском языке мн. ч. от слова ***господин*** — ***господа***.
Поэтому ни один из предложенных вариантов правильным считаться не может.

Правильно в русском: ***от господ Горнов***.

Comment: В вопросе надо было правильно ВПИСАТЬ фамилию. А как правильно у них склоняется  "госпадин", мы и не знаем)

Comment: @Sharon: _В вопросе надо было правильно ВПИСАТЬ фамилию. А как правильно у них склоняется "госпадин", мы и не знаем)_ === Ну да, ну да…  Не знаем и того, склоняется ли _**у них**_ фамилия Горн. Но почему-то в ответах ссылаемся на _правила Розенталя_  для **русского** языка… 

Comment: Я же фамилию по Розенталю выбираю, которую нужно вписать. А если  задавать все  сочетание, то получим правильный русско-белорусский вариант)  Ну а если и фамилию нельзя по Розенталю, то вопросик надо закрывать)  Очень уж "клопотливый" вопрос.